# how can i solve this error, javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: jsp

i am a novice in webapp developement,  I have this code login.jsp and registration.jsp these jsps should let me log in and register but thats not the case , i get this error message when ever i try to login or register.  *"javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected*". attached to this is my code please let me know what to do, correct me where i am wrong. thanks for the help.

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `passwordsignup_confirm` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

login.jsp
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    String email = request.getParameter("emailsignup");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","shaddy");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members WHERE uname='" + userid + "','" + email + "' and password='" + password + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        out.println("welcome " + userid);
        out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>


Registration.jsp
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String username = request.getParameter("uname");   
    String email = request.getParameter("emailsignup");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String passwordsignup_confirm = request.getParameter(" passwordsignup_confirm ");
    String usernamesignup = request.getParameter("usernamesignup");
    String passwordsignup = request.getParameter("passwordsignup");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","shaddy");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(uname, email,  password,) values ('" + username + "','" + email + "','" +password + "','" + passwordsignup_confirm + "'");
    if (i > 0) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", username);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the database name in the URL ,

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root","shaddy");
```

should be something like this ,

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","shaddy"
```

where `test` is your database name

Update :

Also this query ,

```
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(uname, email,  password,) values ('" + username + "','" + email + "','" +password + "','" + passwordsignup_confirm + "')");
```

add a brace like above in it.

Comment: San krish, Thanks for the help! i have added the database name that is settled now, but problem is popping up

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') values ('null','null','null','null'' at line 1

Comment: @ San Krish , thanks very much i followed your updated answer and everything is now working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the name of your db in the URL used for connection:

```
drivermanager.getconnection("localhost:3306/《dbname》");
```

Hope this was useful!